# python - how do I convert sequence in the dates

Tags: python, datetime

below is my dataframe with one column i.e. Date

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date' : ['2014-03-27', '2014-03-28', '2014-03-31', '2014-04-01', '2014-04-02', '2014-04-03', '2014-04-04', '2014-04-07','2014-04-08', '2014-04-09']})
```

assume that the dtype is datetime64[ns]

I want to convert it to format %d-%m-%Y

I used this formula

```
df['Date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x.strftime("%d-%m-%Y"),"%d-%m-%Y"))
```

but the sequencing still didnt change - am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You're just converting the dates back to the same dates. Why do you expect anything to change?

Comment: What do you mean by the sequencing? You're not doing anything to sort the dataframe.

Comment: I want output in the form of %d-%m-%Y" and datetime64 format

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),"%d-%m-%Y"))
```

Read it in the way it is, then print it the way you want it.

Comment: no that didnt work for me

Answer (score 0):

Use `dt.strftime`:

```
df["Date"] = df["Date"].dt.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
```

Comment: It will change the data type of the column to `object`

Comment: These will store your datetime values as strings. If you want them to remain as datetime, you can't choose how they're formatted i.e %d-%m-%Y

Comment: actually thats right, it got converted to object!

Comment: I want output in the form of %d-%m-%Y" and datetime64 format, if thats feasible.

Comment: Do that in your UI, not the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You example dataset doesn't have data of type **datetime64[ns]**, so lets convert them first

**Code**

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime

# your dataset
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2014-03-27', '2014-03-28', '2014-03-31', '2014-04-01', '2014-04-02', '2014-04-03', '2014-04-04', '2014-04-07','2014-04-08', '2014-04-09']})

# convert to datetime64[ns] type
df['Date']=df['Date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d"))
print(df['Date'].dtype)

# convert to formatted string
df['Date']=df['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime("%d-%m-%Y"))
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
datetime64[ns]

         Date
0  27-03-2014
1  28-03-2014
2  31-03-2014
3  01-04-2014
4  02-04-2014
5  03-04-2014
6  04-04-2014
7  07-04-2014
8  08-04-2014
9  09-04-2014
```

Comment: then again it converts to object, I want output in the form of %d-%m-%Y" and datetime64 format